# Does fetch api or whatwg-fetch modify response with status code 304 to 200?

Tags: reactjs, http, fetch-api

I'm using Etags in the response headers for dynamic resources, and my client is sending future requests for the same resource with the If-None-Match header.

The client and server are interacting perfectly, and I get 304 responses if the data was not modified. I can see this on the nginx logs on my server, and the browser network tab on Firefox. However, when i log the exact same response from the whatwg-fetch response status, I'm getting 200.

Although react doesn't re-render if there is not diff in the data, all the processing till that point (dispatching actions, running custom data manipulation etc) are being executed, which is consuming too much memory.

I'm using react-boilerplate, which is internally whatwg-fetch, and too far out to make a U-turn and start using xhrHttpRequests, which apparently don't have this problem from the scant resources I found in other parts of the web.

Please help; I can attach logs and notes if need be. Thanks :)

Comment: You mean the `If-None-Match` header, right?

Comment: yes, my bad.. but i'm sure the headers are right, cuz like i said, my nginx logs and the firefox network tab show 304